# jquery color picker plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I'm using this jquery color picker plugin http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/ in my web application. Everything is working perfect, but when I try to set the original color in the palette on **onBeforeShow** it is not working.

HTML

```
<div id="ncolor"></div><div id="ncolorpicker"><span id="ncpicker"></span></div>
```

Jquery

```
$("#ncolor").click(function(){
    var a = $("#ncolor").css("background-color");
    $("#ncolorpicker").show();
    $("#ncpicker").show().ColorPicker({
    flat: true,
    onBeforeShow: function () {
                  alert("yes");
                  $(this).ColorPickerSetColor(a);
    },
    });
});
```

I'm using **onChange**, **onSubmit** both are working, but not for **onBeforeShow**. I'm not even getting the **alert message** inside **onBeforeShow**.

What I need is I want to set the **background-color** of **#ncolor** in the color palette before showing. Why it is not even entering into **onBeforeShow**? Could anyone guide me?

Thanks!

Comment: What browser are you using? IE might break on that last comma },

Comment: It is not working on any browser. I checked it :(

Comment: Hmm... maybe you just missed a line in the above example, but you didn't close the click handler - you need another `});`

Comment: Sorry @jfrej that's a mistake I've done here not in my actual code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that onBeforeShow doesn't fire in the flat mode.

In the flat mode you can set the initial colour using the `color` property:

```
.ColorPicker({flat: true, color: '#00ff00'});
```

Please note, in Firefox, $("#ncolor").css("background-color") returns a string in the rgb(,,) format.
`color` accepts # strings (#00ff00) or rgb objects like this {r: 0, g: 255, b: 0}

So you might need to do some conversion first.

Also, in your code you are calling `.ColorPicker()` on each click. This is unnecessary.

Instead, you can call `.ColorPicker()` once to set up the ColorPicker. Then on click you only need to call `.ColorPickerSetColor()` and your showing/hiding functions.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ncpicker").ColorPicker({
        flat: true,
        // Initial colour here:
        color: '#0000ff'
    });
    $("#ncolor").click(function(){
        // Use your dynamic colour here - may change each time:
        $('#ncpicker').ColorPickerSetColor('#00ffff');

        // Put here your showing/hiding functionality.
    });
});
```

Quick example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfrej/853bv/
(with showing & hiding taken from the http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/ example).

Comment: No it is working only at the first time. I want to set the colopickersetcolor on click and change.

Comment: "No it is working only at the first time." - what is working? onBeforeShow?

Comment: How to avoid calling .ColorPicker() on every click?

Comment: When I click the #ncolor it showing the correct color which I've given in color property, but when I close and click the second time the color changes from the initial color **#00ff00**

Comment: I want to set the $("#ncolor").css("background-color") hex value for every click, it must change automatically. But I can't do that like they shown here http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/#colorpickerField1

Comment: Yes I'm using the flat mode, that is displaying perfect on my web app.

Comment: What problem is, the javascript performer,compiler or something is not even entering into onBeforeShow. It is not even performing the task I've given inside **onBeforeshow**, not even that **alert("yes")**

Comment: Because onBeforeShow doesn't happen in the flat mode. You need to call .ColorPicker() before the click(). And in the click you only need the code for showing and hiding and for ColorPickerSetColor if the color changes.

Comment: So what can I do for setting the color in the palette dynamically in flat mode?

Comment: I updated my answer and linked to a jsfiddle which uses a ColorPicker in the flat mode and supports setting a new colour on each click.